# Integer parameter in pandas DataFrame.drop function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, int, multiple-columns

In following line of code

```
 X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
```

Could you please explain what does number `1` do?

From documentation I understand that `DataFrame.drop` function drops desired column named `'label'` from dataframe and returns new dataframe without this column. But I dont understand what does this particular integer parameter `1` do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is parameter `axis` in [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). It is same as `axis=1`. And it means you need remove columns from `DataFrame` which are specify in first parameter `labels`:

`labels` is omited most times.
Parameter `axis` can be removed if need remove row with `index`, because by default `axis=0`.
Parameter `axis=1` is sometimes replaced by `1`, because less text, but it is worse readable.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label':[1,2,3],
                   'label1':[4,5,6],
                   'label2':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   label  label1  label2
0      1       4       7
1      2       5       8
2      3       6       9

print (df.drop(['label'], 1))
   label1  label2
0       4       7
1       5       8
2       6       9

#most commonly used
print (df.drop(['label'], axis=1))
   label1  label2
0       4       7
1       5       8
2       6       9

print (df.drop(labels=['label'], axis=1))
   label1  label2
0       4       7
1       5       8
2       6       9
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna drop data called 'age' and you'll have to point it's a column.

So when you drop 'age' from data type

`x = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))`.

If age is axis x

`x = np.array(data.drop([predict], 0))`